# Sounds stopping too soon in MediaPlayer :: Android

Tags: android, android-widget, media-player, listener, audio

Ok well I have been fighting with this for a while now and have soundboard apps that I havn't ran into this problem in.  I am developing a widget that allows for a sound to be played when a button is pressed on the widget.

I am assuming I am just not using the setOnPreparedListener properly but basically what is happening is that some of my sounds play correctly and more likely than not the sounds will cut off the last part noticeable by word or sound effect missing.  Below is my code please let me know if you have any idea what's wrong with the code or post a working revision.

Thanx in advance.

```
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            /** Get our place holder for quotes & sounds. */
            int s = UpdateService.getQuoteNumber();

            /** Check if a sound is playing if so... stop and reset it. */
            if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){mp.stop();mp.reset();}

            /** Create a new mediaplayer and set looping. */
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, SoundsClicked.randomSound[s]);
            mp.setLooping(false);

            /** Try to prepare the sound/mediaplayer, if not report error & type. */
            try {mp.prepare();} 
                catch (IllegalStateException e) {e.printStackTrace();Log.e(Integer.toString(s), "IllegalStateException");} 
                catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();Log.e(Integer.toString(s), "IOException");}              

            /** Check if the sound is prepared, if so play it. */
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                    while (mp.isPlaying()) {};
                }
            });
            return flags;}
```

This is called from a service (obviously from the onStartCommand) but figured I would throw that out there for those not familiar with some of the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Android 2.2, there are apparently some problems with the MediaPlayer cutting off the last X% of at least some audio files.  I'm running in to that problem with the app I'm currently working on.  I haven't found if there is a solution or not.

Comment: A few more notes from my investigations: On the sound files I'm working with at least, I have a problem with the end getting cut off when playing the sound with a MediaPlayer, but the same sounds play properly if played with the SoundPool.  (Unfortuantely, not so helpful if you need to know the progress of the sound files like I do.)  Also, my sounds get truncated when played in the emulator and on some actual devices.  On the Galaxy Tab they don't though.  I'm guessing Samsung has does some custom work on the Tab, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is only pertaining to 2.2? I have the same problem on a 2.3 device right here. Any info on when this is fixed?

Comment: I don't know if this problem is 2.2 only. It may be 2.2+. I believe there were some significant changes to the audio stack in 4.0, but I don't know if this issue has been fixed or not.